# Ethernet-based geomagic touch(phantom omni) ROS package

Tags: ros

I'm new in ROS and trying to find the way to connect ethernet-based geomagic touch and UR3.
Firstly, I want to make an ethernet-based geomagic touch work on ROS. It seems all the packages are for firewire versions. I found 1 package (made by jdrew1303) for ethernet, but it's not working (it's working, but no nodes) Does anybody know how to run an geomagic touch on ROS?